# Compilation Error in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version

Am sure, it has been answered before, but i don't know the way to find the exact solution. I took whole day to find the solution but i entirely stuck with this.

I was worked with my project nicely on day before yesterday. I designed many modules for doing my project further. AS usual i opened and started doing (I didn't get any errors) my project today in visual studio. To execute my old project(coding) once again, i checked in browser, as soon as i did, my face gone too bad :( because of this strange error. Error is,

**Compilation Error**

**Description** :  An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:**CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' could not be opened -- 'Error importing module 'System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll' of assembly 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' -- An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. '

**Source Error:**

```
[No relevant source lines]
```

This is the error am facing till now. I don't where I'm wrong.

**I did deleting temporary files in this area : C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files. But again I'm getting the root folder when am running the project**

Any help, would be more and more helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your application being compiled as a 32-bit app? The "incorrect format" usually relates to the bitness of one or more of the assemblies involved.

Comment: @Michael Yes it's working as a 32 bit app. So what i need to do for this ?.

Comment: Check your dependency chain for any 64 bit assembly. If your application has no specific reason to be compiling for 32-bit arch, try building for either Any CPU or 64-bit.